# Étymologie du mot « brouillon »

Tags: étymologie, histoire

La première version d'un écrit qui sera ensuite mis au net (un premier travail avec corrections) destiné à être recopié fait partie des significations du mot *brouillon*. D'où vient cette signification ?

[Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/brouillon) n'en parle pas. J'ai trouvé seulement le lemme du [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brouillon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On trouve le sens recherché et l'étymologie à partir du dictionnaire de l'Académie ;

> II. BROUILLON n. m. XVIe siècle. Dérivé de brouiller au sens de « griffonner ».
>   Premier état d'un texte destiné à être retouché, corrigé, puis recopié. Faire un brouillon. Un cahier de brouillon. Le brouillon d'une lettre, d'une copie. Écrire sans brouillon. Faire des exercices, une rédaction au brouillon. Conserver les brouillons. En apposition. Papier brouillon, papier médiocre destiné à cet usage. COMPT. Voir Brouillard II.

Answer (score 3):

Il faut simplement sélectionner le [deuxième onglet](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brouillon/1) au TLF (et la [deuxième vedette](https://www.littre.org/definition/brouillon.2) au Littré) et non pas se contenter de rester sur l'adjectif :

> [...] **A. −** 1549 subst. « qui met le trouble dans les affaires »
>   (Est.); av. 1580 adj. (Montaigne, IV, 195 dans Littré). **B. −**
>   1551-1630 « premier travail avec corrections, destiné à être recopié »
>   (Aubigné, [*Mémoires*](https://archive.org/details/mmoiresdethodor00lalagoog/page/n475) ds [Gdf. Compl.](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/brouillon)). Dér. de [brouiller](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brouiller)*;
>   suff. [-on](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-on/0)* (-on : I. A. 3 c [Le dér. marque le résultat ou l'objet de l'action]) (TLFi)
>
> ---
>
> Les deputes de la seigneurie vinrent visiter ses papiers ou ils
>   trouverent un *brouillon* de la vie de feu Monsieur. (Aubigné ds.
>   Godefroy Complément)

On parlait à l'évidence du sens B « premier travail avec corrections, destiné à être recopié ». Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* ajoute le participe « brouillé » entre guillemets à cette phrase (*premier travail « brouillé »*) confirmant le sens du dérivé employé, qui l'est éventuellement au figuré pour « ébauche, esquisse ».

Answer (score 1):

Étymologie de ***« brouillon »***:

> [Déverbal](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9verbal#fr-nom) de [brouiller](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brouiller#fr) avec le suffixe -on.

Source: [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brouillon)